# Will a Pokemon in an out of state gym come back?

Tags: pokemon-go

I live in Iowa and recently went out to Washington state for a wedding and left my Vaporeon in a gym there, it has been in the gym for 25 days which for me is an  unusually long amount of time. Did I just screw myself out of a Pokemon?

Comment: Would you consider accepting an answer by clicking the green tick?

Answer (score 25):

No, don't worry.
Even if your Pokemon is really far away from you, it still belongs to you. You can see it in your Pokemon list, even if it's now defending a foreign gym.
The distance from you and your Pokemon doesn't really do anything.

Comment: They probably just put their pokemon in an out of the way gym with not much traffic. That happens. There is posts on the PoGo subreddit of gyms being held for a full year. I personally have a cemetery I go to sometimes where its very much out of the way, and will often hold gyms for 10+ days. Its possible that Phoenix just put his pokemon in a gym somewhere that is closed for winter, and thus will not be accessible until spring.

Comment: @PhoenixChase if you really want it back, maybe look up the local community of PoGo where your pokemon is, and ask nicely if someone may go liberate your pokemon. I did it a few times in my PoGo regional group. Hey, been at that church for a few days, need my 50 for the day, anybody can bump me off? And usually it happens.

Comment: @Fredy31 another way is to brag about your unbeaten leader of the gym, wait a few minutes and a flyer will kindly free the gym for you :)

Comment: Agreed.  I had one in a gym for almost a year.  Too bad I didn't get a raftload of credit for that.

Comment: @Thierry let me guess, it got taken out a day where you already had your 50 so it was gone for a year for nothing?

Comment: @Fredy31 No, I got my 50.  But I remember the early days when you would get paid coins for every day

Answer (score 10):

Distance doesn't seem to matter.

I traveled from Virginia to New Jersey and left a Pokémon at a gym on the Shore. It came back after I returned home.

Answer (score 10):

Pokémon will return to you from wherever.
It does need to be defeated, so untill another trainer will take the gym from you, it will stay there.
You can't let Pokémon return manually, so you'll just have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely impossible for a Pokemon to be stuck in a gym. Though, the distance does not affect any part of the speed of the return of the Pokemon.
In fact, the distance does not affect anything. The Pokemon will return to you eventually.